# Append query Access not working as expected

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables, both equal. For the example let's call them `Table A` and `Table B`. 
`Table B` is an exact copy of `Table A` - but without the data.

`Table A` holds engineering data and a `DATE` field. 
I have written some code that does some calculations etc. and after those calculations, it should `APPEND` the data from `Table A` to `Table B` so as to keep a historical reference to the data.

Now, I can append from `Table A` to `Table B` with the following Query:

```
INSERT INTO [Table B] SELECT [Table A].* FROM [Table A]
```

This works once. The second time I run it (whith another date in `Table A`) `Table B` is not updated. Why? What am I missing here?

Probably something silly.. But I can't seem to figure it.

Of course I can do a loop in code and fill it record for record.. but that's slow.

*tables have autonumber key fields and duplicates are allowed on all other fields.

Answer (score 0):

nvr mind..

"INSERT INTO [Table B] SELECT * FROM [Table A]"

works.

Still strange though that the original query works once.. but ok. Solved